# The $p$-adic integers as an inverse limit of $\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime and $I=\mathbb{Z^+}$. Let $A_i=\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z}$ and let $\gamma_{ji}$ be the natural projection maps $\gamma_{ji}:$ $a$ (mod $p^j$) $\rightarrow a$ (mod $p^i$). The Inverse limit is called the ring of p-adic integers and is denoted by $\mathbb{Z_p}$.

(a) show that every element of $\mathbb{Z_p}$ can be written uniquely as an infinite formal sum $bo+b_1p+b_2p^2+b_3p^3+...$ with each $b_i \in \{0,1,2,....p-1\}$. Describe the rules for adding and multiplying such formal sums corresponding to addition and multiplication. [write a least residue in each $\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z}$ in its base p expansion and then describe the maps $\gamma_{ji}$. (Note in particular that $\mathbb{Z_p}$ is uncountable.

Can someone help me with this problem. I came up with the following:

Suppose $(x_1,x_2, \cdots)$ is in $\mathbb{Z_p}$. Then, by using the definition of an inverse limit, we can define the $b_i's$ recursively as $b_0=x_1$ and $b_{i+1}=\frac{x_{i+2}-x_{i+1}}{p^{i+1}}$. Note that since $x_{i+2}$ and $x_{i+1}$ are the same mod $p^{i+1}$, this is indeed an integer.

The unique part of the problem is very confusing. What does the book mean by unique? It has not given us a notion of equality in this set of formal prime power series. Am I supposed to define when two series are equal on my own? Maybe the notion of equality is that two series are equal iff they have the same coefficient for every prime power. If yes, how do I go about proving that the representation is unique.

Comment: One of the obstacles here is that, although apparently Hensel originally did think of the type of expansion you mention in (a), this is a bad representation of p-adic integers. Rather, a p-adic integer can usefully be thought of as a sequence $n_1\mod p^1$, $n_2\mod p^2$, ... such that $n_k=n_{k-1}\mod p^{k-1}$. So you are entirely justified in finding problems with that flawed description. Just never mind it, is my advice, except to note that it does not work well.

Comment: @paulgarrett Thanks for the info! I think we can modify my problem by requiring that the $x_i's$ be in their least form as elements of $\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: There is no obligation to choose representatives for $\mathbb Z/p^n$. Choosing representatives creates needless problems and pointless details. This is similar to _not_ thinking of a quotient group $G/H$ by normal subgroup $H$ as a "set of cosets". It is a group in its own right, and there is no compulsion to choose representatives for cosets, etc.

Comment: I thought it would help in proving uniqueness

Comment: @paulgarrett: what's wrong with viewing $p$-adic integers as infinite formal sums? There is no essential difference between that representation and the one you prefer.

Comment: @RobArthan, the fake power series version has clunky multiplication and addition, for one. Proving associativity and distributivity is a minor nightmare. In contrast, the genuine proj limit model (as a certain subset of cartesian product of the limitands) effortlessly gives the correct multiplication, and all the properties we expect are automatic.

Answer (score 1):

1. To add on to  your comment you can choose  $_i'$s  to be elements of $ℤ/_ℤ$ in the construction of the inverse limit $Z_p$. So, you do not need to worry about that.
2. Your notion of equality of the two series is fine. Using this and a simple induction argument you can show the representation is unique. Write down first few terms perhaps.
3. You can also find a map from the infinite power series to $Z_p$ and show this is the inverse of the map from $Z_p$ to the power series ring.
   This may not be required for your problem but it's useful computation wise later on.

Comment: Please use MathJax. I cannot see several symbols in your answer on my device.

Comment: ok sorry about that

Comment: fixed  symbols hope visible now